# Could not create the view: org.eclipse.pde.runtime.LogView - android

Tags: android, layout, view

I don't know why but I'm keep getting this error everytime I try to change something in my xml layout. I really don't know what cause this problem to occur. I didn't really do anything in my project.

Here is my layout xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.todo.MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem just now by change the android version to use when rendering layouts to API 19, by default it's API 20

Answer (score 0):

Look in /.metadata/.log to see what error is occurring.